# Issues with publishing npm package on private gitlab registry

Tags: npm, gitlab, registry, npm-publish

I have a (test) npm package named `@myScope/test` which I want to publish into a private gitlab registry within a gitlab project whose address is

```
https://gitlab.<something>/myId/test-npm-registry/
```

with ID 9630

First, I'm a bit confused with `npm login` and `.npmrc`. If I understand correctly, answers given to `npm login` end-up as a couple of lines into `.npmrc`, is that right?

So essentially, to instruct npm about authenticating to a registry, one can either:

- manually edit `.npmrc`
- use `npm config set`
- use `npm login`

Based on what I read [on the gitlab help](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/#authenticate-to-the-package-registry), I've inserted the following lines into my `.npmrc`:

```
@myScope:registry=https://gitlab.<something>/api/v4/projects/9630/packages/npm/
'//gitlab.<something>/api/v4/projects/9630/packages/npm/:_authToken'="${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}"
```

*Note: I had to use the project ID, having issues with the url format.*

I have also added the following bit into the package.json :

```json
publishConfig":{
  "@myScope:registry": "https://gitlab.<something>/api/v4/projects/9630/packages/npm/"
}
```

Finally, I've created a token in gitlab, with `"api, read_api, read_registry, write_registry"` rights and I have assigned the token to the `GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN` variable:

```
GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN="xk4L7xxvzHuykyKawxQZ"
```

When I do `npm publish` I'm getting the following message :

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - PUT https://gitlab.<something>/api/v4/projects/9630/packages/npm/@myScope%2ftest-npm-registry

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

The logs doesn't help, nor does the verbose mode. Also, I'm not getting if I have to perform an explicit `npm login` or if the configuration in the `.npmrc` (with the token) should do the trick. I actually cannot do `npm login` because the username has an `@` character in it and npm refuses it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's the name of your package in package.json? Is it just `test` or is it `@myId/test`?